# Is there a way I can compile C# code from C#?

Tags: compilation

I am making a function in C# that takes C# code as a string, and compiles it into an EXE file and then can pass info to the EXE when executed. Is there a way that I can compile code in C# (from C#) without making a compiler for C#?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly is possible, check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpcompilation.create?view=roslyn-dotnet.  You can create the syntax tree from your code using the syntax parser (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxfactory.parsesyntaxtree?view=roslyn-dotnet).

Comment: When I use that code, it gives me CS0028 and CS0234

Comment: Can you be more specific, like are you getting it when you compile your local code or your syntax tree?  You should get a match to specific code as well.